# Why Ida pseudo-code translate test as AND?

Tags: ida, assembly, x86, hexrays

In IDA when disassembling a x86 EXE file there is a line

```
test byte ptr [ebp+XXX], cl
```

Before this line `cl` has a value of `0x11`

The Hex-Rays decompiler plugin translates it as `if (v10 &0x11)`.

Why is `test` decompiled like `and`?

Comment: It seems likely you are referring to the Hex-Rays decompiler. This integrates very well with IDA and is by the same company. However, they are separate products and you can use IDA without a decompiler. It might be worth updating your question.

Comment: did  you ever read the [`test` instruction's manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test), or at least google for `x86 test instruction`?

Answer (score 6):

[`test`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test) is basically an [`and`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/and) instruction except it doesn't update the left operand.
In the other hand, [`cmp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp) is the equivalent of [`sub`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sub) instruction except it doesn't update the left operand.

To sum up:

```
if (v & n)
```

Is compiled as `test` instruction.

```
if (v == n)
```

Is compiled as `cmp` instruction (or `test reg, reg` is n is 0x0)

```
v = a & n
```

Is compiled as `and` instruction.